# How to set in a td image and text position

Tags: html, html-table

I want to set up next to my image a text - they are in one td, but when i set upt the text it starts from the end of the picture, how to set it up to start from the starting point next to the picture ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
   style="float:left;
```

on the Image. This class will make the image float to the left and other text will start just after that.

try it

Answer (score 1):

Lots of options:

- Set the `align` attribute of the image to either `left` or `right`
- Put the image in a separate table cell (`<tr><td>Tekst</td><td><img... /></td></tr>`)
- Make the image a floating element by setting `float` to either `left` or `right` using css
- …